# Office365 SSO for WebAPI based applications

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on, office365, azure-active-directory

I've been developing an WebAPI based application with token based authentication implemented and Using angularJs 1.6 as front-end. Requirement is to provide SSO for office365 without navigating user to microsoft login page for consent when user in signed in to application using login page of dashboard. Currently I'm not able to find any way to do that. Kindly guide me in accomplishing that. In my dashboard I'll provide link for any microsoft service. Let's say OutLook. When the user clicks on that link it will open up in new tab. I've been able to accomplish that using SMART LINKS. But for now user need to authenticate again on microsoft's login page.

Kindly help me in accomplishing SSO for that.

Comment: If the user logs in to the dashboard using Azure AD, they should not need to log in again. They will be redirected to the sign in page but go through it directly if they are logged in already and consent has already been granted.

Comment: Generally speaking, if user needs to do consent you have to redirect them.

Comment: I need to use login page of my dashboard.

Comment: Then the answer is basically no. There is a flow which allows you to do non-interactive authentication, but that one does not work if the user: a) has MFA, b) password has expired, c) is federated from MSA or AD

Comment: And several other things are also working behind the scene. E.g Roles Managment based on ad groups and I also need to get token to access published rdweb applications.

Comment: Can you please mention that non-interactive authentication flow?
As we are managing MFA separately using another service provider.

Comment: It's called ROPC, I encourage you to read this first: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications. Personally, I would not use an app that uses this flow. Because I want to give my password to the MS login page, not your app.

Comment: And that might not work either, now that I think about it. The user needs an active session with Outlook to access things there. To get that they need to authenticate against AAD. If they are not authenticated against AAD when they hit the button in your dashboard, well, they will have to login to AAD.

Comment: yes @juunas I was thinking the same how browser would know that user is authenticated with AAD. I've two other options in mind.
1 - Implement SAML.
2 - Go with explicit workflow. In this case can you please recommend some way to manage token for RD published apps and custom roles

Comment: What does RD mean? :)

Comment: Remote Desktop.